# Game UI in Editor is scaled (Unity, Android only)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, editor

Today I started Unity and saw UI of my game is scaled.

Change commit, reinstall Unity, clone project, canvas scaler didn't help.

This issue for Android platform and in Unity app only. If Build in device, all is OK.

Switch platform to other helps too.

I think this is somewhere in Unity settings.

Can you help me please!!! Thanks =D

Normal resolution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQmEs.jpg)

Android resolution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvwMd.jpg)

Comment: You need to set the canvas as scale with screen size and set the expected canvas resolution to one that looks good in your editor. Then, you need to determine if you want the UI to scale evenly (0.5) or with just the width (0.0) or just the height (1.0), or any value in between (0.0->1.0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood you mean Canvas Scaler. But if I change that, the problem is fixed in editor only. If I changed scale to 0.5 on Android device UI will be too small but in editor that is OK. I see resolution of canvas is changed if I switch to Android. Is there settings in Unity? P.S. I updated screenshots in Question. Please can you take a look?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!
This is Low Resolution Aspect Ratios!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS907.png)